# Executing a list of functions

Tags: list, function, ocaml

I'd like to apply a functions stored in a list

```
let functions = [(fun () -> print_string "fun 1"); (fun () -> print_string "fun 2")]
```

with a high-order function like List.iter, to display "fun 1" and "fun 2"

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the way to do it:

```
List.iter (fun f -> f()) functions
```

Your list consists of functions with the signature `unit -> unit`. Therefore, if you supply `()` as a parameter for each function, they will return `unit` which is obvious to use inside `List.iter`.

Comment: An equivalent version, using `BatPervasives` : `List.iter ((|>) ()) functions`